# Kriging with mean data instead of point data

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, error, kriging

[Kriging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kriging) is a technique to predict a realisation of a Gaussian process. The values of the realisation are known at a finite subset of points and we would like to optimally predict the values of the realisation at all other points. In this case optimal means that the mean squared error is minimised.

My question is whether there has been any work on Kriging a realisation based on a set of means of that realisation. For example break a realisation $x(t)$ into four quarters and take the arithmetic mean of each quarter. Using the mean information what is the optimal prediction (Krige) of the undivided realisation?

Comment: This is called the "change of support" problem.  It is extensively discussed in the mining literature.  An early textbook treatment is Journel & Huijbregts (1978). The difficulty is not in finding an "optimal prediction," which is obtained through a natural and simple extension of the usual Kriging equations, but in estimating the variogram (*i.e.*, the covariance model).